# Создание ec2 instance с помощью ansible

Tags: ansible, amazon-web-services

Подскажите как создание ec2 instance с помощью ansible с конкретным название, а если такое название уже есть, то просто пропустить этот шаг и перейти с следующему шагу

Comment: Ты смотрел https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_module.html#examples ? Что именно у тебя вызвало смущение?

Comment: Для начала вам нужен аккаунт на aws.